# Is it possible to use OpenCV's K-Means implementation with arbitrary objects?

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a set of objects that don't intuitively fit into a `cv::Mat`, and I want to cluster them.  I have a distance function defined between any two objects, and I'm already including OpenCV into my project, so it seems convenient to use its implementation.

So, my question is, given a defined distance function, can I use OpenCV's k-means clustering implementation when the objects aren't intuitively `cv::Mat` compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately OpenCV's [KMeans](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html?highlight=kmeans#double%20kmeans%28InputArray%20data,%20int%20K,%20InputOutputArray%20bestLabels,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20attempts,%20int%20flags,%20OutputArray%20centers%29) is hardcoded to handle only floatig point, single precision values. Anything else must be converted, if possible, to be used inside KMeans.

It should not be something impossible to send a distance function to a generic KMeans algorithm, but the current implementation does not allow it. All it can handle are multi-dimensional floating point feature spaces, stored in `cv::Mat`